# JPA doesn't find Entity when using JTA

Tags: jpa, jta

Im using JPA and i wanted to use JTA.

DataSource and JNDI are correctly set and working BUT if the database
is empty (tables not yet created) JTA is not working!

Here is what i mean. If i use the following persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="MyUnit" transaction-type="JTA">

        <jta-data-source>jdbc/MyDB</jta-data-source>

        <class>de.MyEntity</class>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

It says that MyEntity is not an Entity. The EntityManager cant find it.

If i use this persistence.xml to build the database and import the data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">

<persistence-unit name="MyUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <class>de.MyEntity</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="persistence-context.persist-on-commit" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatastore" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="admin" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

it works great! if i now switch back to the persistence.xml above to use
JTA suddenly he is able to find MyEntity as an Entity of the EntityManager.....

So where is the sense here? If i want to create my database using an 
entitymanager and jta it doesnt work but if i dont use jta to create it
and switch back to jta when everything is created suddenly i can use jta
and he doesnt complains.